# How to edit all values of a td that have the same class with values from an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I have a big table that takes inputs, then I use Javascript to take the values from those inputs - I give them the save Tag so that I can collect all of them and get them into an array. Then I do some calculations and end up with another array with data that I want to add to my table. My question is: Is there any easy way to add this data to the TDs that are next to the input TDs? I was looking for something simple like when I use `document.getElementsByTagName()` but reversed so it actually adds values to all the elements that have that tag.

Not sure if I was explicit enough...

(Disclaimer: I'm not even sure if the way i'm doing these calculations is correct)

```
<head>
<title>calculadora v2.0</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
var Nivel= [];
var Pontos_Base=[10,16,20,24,10,10,42,512,19,0,24,10,6,6,6,5,6,5,8];
var Pontos_Finais=[];

    function asseb_calc(){
        var Nivel = document.getElementsByTagName("asseb_edificios");
        for (var i = 0; i < Nivel.length; i++) {
        var x= Math.round(Pontos_Base[i]*Math.pow(1.2,Nivel[i]-1));
        Pontos_Finais.push(x);
        }
    }


</script>
```

```
    <body>
<table><tr><th>Edifício</th><th>Nível</th><th>Pontos</th><th >Fazenda Ocupada</th></tr>
    <tr><td> Edificio Principal</td><td><input onchange="asseb_calc()" type="number" class="asseb_edificios"></td><td class="asseb1" class="center">0</td><td class="center">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Quartel</td><td><input onchange="asseb_calc()" type="number" class="asseb_edificios"></td><td class="asseb1" class="center">0</td><td class="center">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Estábulo</td><td><input onchange="asseb_calc()" type="number" class="asseb_edificios"></td><td class="asseb1" class="center">0</td><td class="center">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td> Oficina</td><td><input onchange="asseb_calc()" type="number" class="asseb_edificios"></td><td class="asseb1" class="center">0</td><td class="center">0</td></tr></table>
```

Tried erasing all the CSS from it and some extra rows it had.
The idea was for the values from `Pontos_Finais` to go to TDs that have `class="asseb1"` as their class.

Sorry for bad coding I'm trying learning on my own :p

Answer (score 0):

`onchange="asseb_calc()"` is not the best way to handle an event but using this approach you can do the following `onchange="asseb_calc(this)"` where `this` will represent the html element of the event i.e. your input tag. You have to change your function definition to:

```
   function asseb_calc(element){
     // your calculating code here
     // ...
     // you have your input element so you can change it, 
     // or change its parent, or find the parent `tr` 
     // i.e you have your reference point          
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You use the parentNode and "nextSibling" attributes to go up to the input's TD parent, and then to the next TD.

```
function asseb_calc(){
        var Nivel = document.getElementsByTagName("asseb_edificios");
        for (var i = 0; i < Nivel.length; i++) {
        var x= Math.round(Pontos_Base[i]*Math.pow(1.2,Nivel[i]-1));
        Pontos_Finais.push(x);
        Nivel[i].parentNode.nextSibling.innerHTML = x;
        }
    }
```